# Changing subplot titles in seaborn's FacetGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

I am trying to plot a bar chart on a FacetGrid using seaborn library. But I am having trouble adding string labels to the chart below.

For instance, the Gender variable has two values, 0 and 1. However, instead using integer values, I want to label these values as "Male" and "Female", respectively at this chart. How can I do that?

```
import seaborn as sbn    
grid = sbn.FacetGrid(df_train, row='Gender', col='Loan_Status', size=2.2, aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sbn.barplot, 'Married', 'ApplicantIncome', alpha=.5, ci=None)
grid.add_legend()
```

[image: Bar chart]

Comment: The easiest option would be to rename them in your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought about that. But I think there should be a easier way without editing the data frame.

Comment: Well, using an dataframe with the updated Data would be one line of code. Changing all titles manually would not be possible in a single line, so "easy" is pretty much depending on the point of view. In any case, since it seems you want to go the second road, I marked as duplicate of an existing question on exactly this subject.